# Definition of sheaves

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am trying to understand the chapter about sheaves in the book by Warner "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups". A sheaf $J$ of $K$-modules over $M$ is defined as a topological space $J$ together with a map (called projection) $\pi: J \rightarrow M$ such that

(i)  $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism

(ii) $\pi^{-1}(m)$ is a $K$-module for each $m \in M$

(iii) module operations are continuous.

I am puzzled by the first two conditions. My understanding was that homeomorphisms should preserve the dimension. How can its inverse be not a point but say a vector space which is a certain $K$-module?

Comment: Consider the standard map $x\to e^{ix}$ from the real line to a circle. In a neighborhood near any $x_0,$ this map is $1-1.$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827439/why-can-projection-function-on-x-times-s-be-regarded-as-a-local-homeomorphism).

Comment: That said, I don't know how this particular definition works. Most other types of sheaves don't have this property, and it seems like it means that it would imply $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is a discrete space, which would make (iii) trivial.